# with react native 0.61 what does this mean const App: () => React$Node = () => {

Tags: reactjs, react-native

recently i moved to react native 0.61.2 and in the app.js the class was starting with ***const App: () => React$Node = () => {}*** and i am unable to know, what the heck does this mean.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276469/const-app-reactnode-what-does-it-mean-this-instruction