# const App: () => React$Node = () => {...}: what does it mean this instruction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

on `react-native init ProjectName`, the main app file `App.js` contains the declaration of a component in the following way:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {...}
```

What does it mean this instruction?

I mean, I'm used to component defined as `const App = () => {...}`, so I don't understand, in particular, the expression in between`: () => React$Node`.

Comment: Are you sure it's a JS file?  That looks like typescript.

Comment: @Phix I think it's using Flow

Comment: ahh makes sense.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Its type definition from Flow, it means that constant App is of type function and it returns ReactNode.

ReactNode is one of these types: `ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`

This means the function App can return, any valid JSX (in react native its anything from View, Text, .etc), ReactFragment, React.Portal, boolean, null, undefined

If you are confused about the dollar sign, here is a link with explanation.
https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/

There are separate sections for "private" or "magic" types with a $ in the name. See the note here and comment here. Update: Some these types are now documented here.

For easy you can think of it as its `Node` from `React` (think of it as scope/namespace)

Comment: Typescript would be `ReactNode`, without `$`

Comment: I seet that the sample React Native uses Flow. But I don't find any documentation in Flow about `React$Node`. Can you help me to clarify this point?

Comment: ok @marco my bad its Flow, not typescript but as I mentioned in my answer React node is basically any element you can render, will put whole definition into answer.

Comment: fine, but I still miss something about `React$Node` (the dollar sign...), I mean, in Flow doc there is not any reference to it

Comment: @marco fixed the answer, ReactNode is not from Flow, its only Flow definition for React specific type

Comment: @marco and if its the dollar sign you dont get, you can read up on it in answer aswel :-) if there is anything else, hit me up

Answer (score 4):

It is also a type of declaration of App component as a function but you can change it to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5
    }
});
```

Don't forget to remove statement Export default App in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

React$Node is a type defined in react.js

```
declare type React$Node =
  | null
  | boolean
  | number
  | string
  | React$Element<any>
  | React$Portal
  | Iterable<?React$Node>;
```